# Access Linked Table Manager missing, can't change linked database

Tags: microsoft-access

In an Access file the "Linked Table Manager" is missing in Office 2010, in fact the only menus are File and Home are visible. How do I unhide the Linked Table Manager so I can fix the location of the associated database? The menu does not hide for any other accdb files, just this one in particular.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was **Privacy Options**, not "Options". It's critical that people answer questions accurately...though it would certainly help if corporations like Microsoft didn't keep redesigning the GUI of their software every two years purely for the sake of change.

---

- Go to File / **Privacy Options**.
- Click on **Current Database** on the left panel menu.
- Scroll down to the header **Ribbon and Toolbar Options**.
- Ensure both options, *Allow Full Menus* and *Allow Default Shortcut Menus*, are checked.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what steps you performed in "Privacy Options". You've marked this as the answer to your question, but there is not enough details for the next person with the same problem to resolve.

Comment: @sunk818 Done. :-)

Comment: I guess it could be useful to hide the menus in certain circumstances though it totally threw us off because we were dealing with someone else's mess. Unfortunately I do not know how similar, if even available, these options are and are accessible in other versions of Access since Microsoft loves to change the GUI at every change. I hope this helps others because it drove us insane.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is just a ACCDB not an encrypted ACCDE, you should be able to customize your ribbon to bring up the External Tools ribbon as part of the Main Tab:

- Go to File, Options, Customize Ribbon
- Navigate to External Data
- Click Add to have it show on the right side

[image]

If you correctly added External Data to the right side, it should appear as a ribbon option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can not access the options menu. I've updated the question with partial screenshots to show you what I *do* have access to.

Comment: You could try creating a blank database, then import the tables to it. That should copy the data without the Access interface restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

> The menu does not hide for any other accdb files, just this one in particular.

Check the file extension of the troublesome database file. If the file extension is `.accdr` then Access will open it with the same settings as the Microsoft Access Runtime. To restore the normal Access menus for this file simply rename it to have the `.accdb` extension.